# divide time between morning 9AM to evening 6PM in to 3hrs time interval using python datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Basically, what I am trying to do is, divide the time between morning 9 AM and evening 6 PM into specified time hours interval

For example, if I specify the time gap interval as 3 hours then I should get the result by dividing the time between 9 to 6 as

```
['2017-05-03 09:00', '2017-05-03 12:00', '2017-05-03 15:00', '2017-05-03 18:00']
```

If I specify the time gap interval as 2 hours then I should get

```
['2017-05-03 09:00', '2017-05-03 11:00', '2017-05-03 13:00', '2017-05-03 15:00', '2017-05-03 17:00']
```

Below is my code for doing it

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
start_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=9, minute=0) #(Morning 9 AM)
end_time = start_time + timedelta(hours=9) # (Evening 6 PM)

result = []
time_interval = 3
while start_time <=end_time:
    result.append(start_time)
    start_time += timedelta(hours=time_interval)

print(result)
```

Basically, I used `while` in the above code to check condition, so is it possible to do the same above logic without using `while` statement and by using some other logic using list comprehension etc .,?

Also if possible I need the output list as

```
[
'2017-05-03 09:00 to 2017-05-03 12:00', 
'2017-05-03 12:00 to 2017-05-03 15:00', 
'2017-05-03 15:00 to 2017-05-03 18:00'
]
```

Comment: Could you convert your dates to second, then you do `delta_t_sec = start_time_sec - end_time_sec/N` where `N` is your time interval. then you can add the `delta_t_sec` to the dates you got `N times`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can solve the problem with [`rrule()` from `dateutil`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) to generate the datetimes in a specified range hourly and then iterating over the results with a specified `step`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from itertools import islice

from dateutil.rrule import HOURLY, rrule

interval = 3
start_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=9, minute=0) #(Morning 9 AM)
end_time = start_time + timedelta(hours=9) # (Evening 6 PM)

stops = islice(rrule(freq=HOURLY, dtstart=start_time, until=end_time), None, None, interval)
print([datetime.strftime(stop, "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M") for stop in stops])
```

Prints:

```
['2017-05-03 09:00', '2017-05-03 12:00', '2017-05-03 15:00', '2017-05-03 18:00']
```

Note that the list comprehension and the `strftime()` calls here are for demonstration purposes only - `stops` is an iterator that "contains" the desired `datetimes`.

And, applying the same `pairwise` helper as @NiL used, we can get to your next desired output:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from itertools import islice, tee

from dateutil.rrule import HOURLY, rrule


def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ...

    https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html
    """
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


interval = 3
start_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=9, minute=0) #(Morning 9 AM)
end_time = start_time + timedelta(hours=9) # (Evening 6 PM)

stops = islice(rrule(freq=HOURLY, dtstart=start_time, until=end_time), None, None, interval)

print(['{0} to {1}'.format(datetime.strftime(start, "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M"),
                           datetime.strftime(stop, "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M"))
       for start, stop in pairwise(stops)])
```

Prints:

```
['2017-03-05 09:00 to 2017-03-05 12:00', '2017-03-05 12:00 to 2017-03-05 15:00', '2017-03-05 15:00 to 2017-03-05 18:00']
```

Comment: Thanks that really helps, but is it possible to get the required output in the above mentioned format? `[
'2017-05-03 09:00 to 2017-05-03 12:00', 
'2017-05-03 12:00 to 2017-05-03 15:00', 
'2017-05-03 15:00 to 2017-05-03 18:00'
]`

Answer (score 0):

something like this might do what you want

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from itertools import tee
start_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=9, minute=0)  # (Morning 9 AM)
end_time = start_time + timedelta(hours=9)  # (Evening 6 PM)

time_interval = 3
delta = 9  # hours


def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ...

    https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html
    """
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


iterations = (delta // time_interval) + 1
result = [start_time+i*timedelta(hours=time_interval)
          for i in range(iterations)]
print(result)

formatted=['{} to {}'.format(
    start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),
    end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
    for start, end in pairwise(result)]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(formatted)
```